# Batch search in php txt file

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to search the ip addresses in the txt file. A single ip address shows the result when I log in, but when I type more than one ip address in the textarea, the result is not found. Can anyone help?

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>search</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form method="POST"> 
        <textarea type="text" name="q" id="q"></textarea> 
        <button type="sumbit">ok</button> 
    </form> 

    <?php if($_POST){ 
        $file = 'check.txt'; 
        $find = $_POST['q']; 
        $contents = file_get_contents($file); 
        $pattern = preg_quote($find, '/'); 
        $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m"; 
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){ 
           echo implode("\n", $matches[0]); 
        } 
        else{ 
           echo "error"; 
        }} ?> 
</body>
```

Sample Check.txt

```
127.0.0.1
44.222.223.22
252.241.351.24
55.244.241.2
241.212.235.42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `filter_var()` function, can do the job fast and keep code simple.

Simple, workable solution to improve:

```
 <?php
    echo'<hr>';
    // Get list from txt file and make an array
    $IP_list=explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('Check.txt'));
    $IP_count=count($IP_list);
    // Get data from textarea and seperate to "words" expecting that every word can be IP
    $IP_input=$_POST['q'];
    $IP_to_check_list=explode(PHP_EOL,$IP_input);
    $IP_to_check_count=count($IP_to_check_list);
    // Loop trough array of "words" from textarea
    for($index_search_for=0;$index_search_for<$IP_to_check_count;$index_search_for++)
    {
        // Check if "word" is IP
        if(filter_var($IP_to_check_list[$index_search_for], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            // If "word" is IP, try to find it in text file
            $found=0;
            for($index_search_at=0;$index_search_at<$IP_count;$index_search_at++)
            {
                if($IP_to_check_list[$index_search_for]==$IP_list[$index_search_at])
                {
                    // If match found - show result and stop loop
                    echo '<strong>'.$IP_to_check_list[$index_search_for].'</strong> is in list<br>';
                    $found=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($found==0)
            {
                echo $IP_to_check_list[$index_search_for].' - no matches<br>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $IP_to_check_list[$index_search_for].' - not an IP<br>';
        }
    }
    echo'<hr>';
    echo'<form method="POST"><textarea name="q" id="q"></textarea><input type=submit value="Ok"></form>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but can't find it in the txt file when I type more than one ip under each other.

Comment: It works if you enter IP adreses to text file seperating them width new line. One line - one IP.

Comment: And enter IP adreses to textarea seperated by spaces.

Comment: For example, I'm doing a search like this. But there are no results.
https://imgur.com/F93D8ZS

Comment: I think it only finds a space, how can I do it by adding it one under the other.

Comment: Problem is in line '$IP_to_check_list=explode(' ',$IP_input);'

Comment: Try change to $IP_to_check_list=explode(PHP_EOL,$IP_input);

Comment: Because you use "new line" to seperate values, not " "(space).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried it, unfortunately no results. When I add a line by line it only finds the last line https://imgur.com/Nl2FXHM

Comment: I was able to process using preg_split, thanks.
$IP_to_check_list = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $IP_input);

I wonder how can I make a permanent search with more than one txt file.

Comment: Read file, save contents to variable, read another, join another file contents to first file contents and repeat until readed all files. Than use "explode" or "preg_split" to convert all to workable array. Maybe loop all array to drop out dublicates.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is working good then for more than one ip address. your if condition should be like below:

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    $matches = array_unique($matches[0]);
    foreach($matches as $match){
        echo "<pre>$match</pre>";
    }
}
```